# to display an image in a html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an image location stored in a json file as a string.Now , i have to get the image location from the json file and have to display it in a html5 canvas.Please help me in doing this.I don't know how to retrieve the image path from the json file using javascript.this is the content of my json file.

```
{"image1":"\/root\/Desktop\/project\/Screenshot.png"}
```

I have to display this image in a html page.
this is my java code to create the json file

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

    public class Simple27 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {

            BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("/root/Desktop/project","Screenshot.png"));
            //the string is written into a json file
            try
            {
                FileWriter wr=new FileWriter("/root/Desktop/project/code/json/imagepath.jsonp");    
                String ip="/root/Desktop/project/Screenshot.png";
                JSONObject imgpath=new JSONObject();
                imgpath.put("image1",ip);
                wr.write(imgpath.toString());
                wr.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this JSON file in your local file system or on some server?

Comment: in my local file system

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your JSON file with `.jsonp` extension.
In that file do write your object like this:

```
jsonContents = [ {"image1":"\/root\/Desktop\/project\/Screenshot.png"} ];
```

Then you can request that file in `<head>` like this:

```
<script src="file://path to your jsonp file"></script>
```

You can access the JSON contents as:

```
<script>
    console.log((jsonContents));
    var contents = jsonContents;

    for(var i=0;i<jsonContents.length;i++){

       var obj = jsonContents[i];
       var imageSrc = obj.image1;
       console.log(imageSrc);
       var img = new Image();
       img.src = imageSrc;
       context.drawImage(img,x,y);  //context = your context variable

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Can't you change that structure in your Java code? because you ll not be able to access JS files in your local file system because of same origin policies. You have to either deploy it in web server or use JSONP callback.

Comment: is jsonContents is a JSONArray?Should i create a JSONArray in java by the name jsonContents and store it in jsonp?

Comment: Ok, but why bother with json then?  The script file could just be `var myImageURL="put your file path here";`

Comment: sorry, I am just a learner in json.I am doing a project in java in which i should store the resultant images in a json file and should get the images from the json file and display it using html5 canvas.Atfirst , i tried it as storing the image as a string but i need to do that for multiple images which includes time and space complexity.So i thought of storing the images with it's path in the json file.